# Nginx change status code so that deleted articles do not disappear from Google search

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

I think have a problem with my rewrite status code. My problem is, if articles will be deleted.

Then, deleted articles are not removed from the Google search. Because then the Temporary Redirect 302 is made. So far I know I then need 410 Status code for it.

I use my own page it was programmed with PHP and MySQL.

My Rules like this

```
rewrite '^/city/(.*)$' /article.php?id=$1 last;
```

How can I make it?

Comment: If you could include more information then it would be helpful. For example, are you using a CMS such as Wordpress? Did you create this website yourself? Do you have any form of URL Rewriting enabled?

Comment: use my own page it was programmed with PHP and MySQL. My Rules like this:   rewrite '^/city/(.*)$' /article.php?id=$1 last;

Comment: in PHP, your scripts can return a header, so long as you haven't started sending output (i.e. started echoing or output html). You can do this by using the code:
http_response_code(410);
You have to do this before sending any output, or PHP will automatically send 200 (OK).